# Stuck on the root while traversing a binary tree in java recursivly

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

This is one of my very first questions here so, bear with me !

I'm trying to traverse through a binary tree which is unbalanced, each node contains a string and a counter as data.The counter counts the number of occurrences of a string inside a text file.

Here is my traverse method:

```
public WordCount traverse(WordCount root) {

    current = root;
    if (current.getCount() > max) {
        var = current;
        max = var.getCount();
    }
    else if (current.getLeftChild() != null) {
        next = current.getLeftChild();
        traverse(next);
    } else if (current.getRightChild() != null) {
        next = current.getRightChild();
        traverse(next);
    }
    return var;
}
```

keep in mind that car,current and next are initialized as WordCount empty objects where their default constructors assigns 1 to their counter variable. Also max is assigned to 0.

I pass the root of the tree as the root argument in the WordCount method, but i always get the most frequent word as the the root of the tree.
It seems that my method is not functioning as it should be. Maybe there is something wrong with my conditions or recursion.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `max is assigned to 0.` then always execute the first part of the if...else ladder. that's the cause, I think.

Comment: @sunkuet02 if i change all the else-if statements into if statements since recursion takes place between the last 2 if statements, i also get the same results.

Comment: Except that `else if` should be changed to `if` as already mentioned, your posted code looks fine. So your problem may be somewhere else. Would it be possible for you to post a [Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: It’a an aside, it seems you’re overusing non-local variables. I understand that `var` and `max` need to be outside your `traverse` method, but as far as I can see, `current` and `next` ought to be local to the method. Maybe I’m missing something.

Comment: Since you’ve changed the if statements, please edit the question and give the new version of the code instead of the old one so we know we are talking about the same code.

Answer (score 0):

This should work!

```
// Assuming max and var are some global variables
public WordCount traverse(WordCount root) {
    if(root == null) {
       max = 0;
       return root;
    }
    if (root.getCount() > max) {
        var = root;
        max = root.getCount();
    }

    if (root.getLeftChild() != null) {
        traverse( root.getLeftChild() );
    }

    if (root.getRightChild() != null) {
        traverse( root.getRightChild() );
    }
    return var;
}
```

We have to traverse both the left and right sub-trees to maximize our word frequency search. So `else` can't be used here as you were stopping at root else going either left branch or right branch which won't guaranty the most frequent word count.

You used many intermediate variables like `current`, `next` which are not only unnecessary but make the code messy and complex too.

### Edit

This snippet is supposed to work considering the tree of `WordCount` is valid and holding information as you're expecting. Otherwise, there might be other problems like `getCount()`, `getLeftChild()` APIs are buggy or the information are not correct as you're assuming per node.

Comment: According to the OP, replacing `else if` statements with plain `if` statements didn't change the results, thus indicating another problem somewhere else. Anyway, he may have done it wrong (he didn't answer previous comments).

Comment: @PatriceGahide Yes I think so. This snippet is supposed to work considering his tree of `WordCount` is valid and holding information as he is expecting. May be there are other problems,.